# UEFI-support for Debian Live-build

Tags: debian, live-usb, uefi, bootable, bios

I'm building a custom Debian using live-build, and after dd-ing the iso to the USB-stick it boots fine on BIOS-computers, however it does not seem to support UEFI, thus not booting on newer computers.

My goal is simple, to create a custom live-Debian which can boot on "any" computer.

Do you have any ideas of how to enable UEFI, or if there are other ways to build a custom Debian-live with better support?

Comment: Does your image have an ESP (EFI system partition) with a boot loader? If yes, then it should work, there's not much more to do to support UEFI. If not, then set up an ESP partition.

Comment: The image created by live-build does not have a ESP. I did try to add this manually but without success. I will look into this a bit more, any hints?

Comment: [Here's a script I use](http://dpaste.com/26B7HSE) to create bootable USB sticks with persistent storage. It's not pretty or resilient but gets the job done for me. If that works for you I can post it as an answer if it doens't maybe you can refine your question and add a bit more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your script Marco. It did work (after realizing I needed to provide an absolute path to the .iso) but for UEFI-computers only (like you say in the file). My goal is to create a stick that is bootable on UEFI and BIOS (i.e. "any" computer).

Comment: I should mention that I do have a working solution, by using an existing .iso (that I did not create) which contains an ESP as well as a persistance-partition. What I can do is to dd that iso to /dev/sdX and then replace the squashfs and kernel to use my debian instead. Yes it's ugly (right?), that's why I'm looking into other options.

Comment: I ended up using ubuntu, which works with both (and also secure boot).

Comment: @MartinSuecia could you paste this script again, im also looking for EFI support. That link you pasted expired...

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach to achieve this.

1. Add common grub related package in `config/package-lists/pkgs.list.chroot` file. eg:

```bash
grub-common
grub2-common
```

2. Add file `config/package-lists/grub-pc.list.binary` and add legacy grub packages

```bash
grub-pc
grub-pc-bin
```

3. Add file `config/package-lists/grub-eefi-amd64.list.binary` for handle uefi` related packages.

```bash
grub-efi
grub-efi-amd64
grub-efi-amd64-bin
```

Finally run the `lb build` command.

Comment: I got conflict errors when having both grub-pc and grup-efi. Removing grub-pc is working fine on debian bookworm.